# Scary Story From a Kids Anthology about a monster that tricks kid into inviting him, then eats him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I feel like this story was in one of those 90's scary kids story anthologies. As I recall the premise was there was a monster in the tree outside of a childs window. It couldn't come in without an invitation so the mean little kid tells it he will invite it in, as long as it only eats his sibling. Then of course when it comes in it eats him.